# how to pass php database id from one html page to another html page using jquery mobile and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

Hi i am working newly with jquerymobile and ajax to build android app using phonegap V2.9. I have little idea about Sql database. I am working with multiple html pages and js pages like register.html, home.html, login.html, editprofile.html, viewprofile.html ...etc and login.js, index.js ...etc here i am submitting a login form using ajax in jquerymobile.

```
html page with form:

<div data-role="page" id="page" data-position="fixed" >
<form id="register-form"  novalidate="novalidate" data-ajax="true">
<div class="text"><input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="email" class="textboxes userBox " id="email" placeholder="Email / Username"  /></div>
<div class="space"></div>
<div class="text"><input type="password" data-clear-btn="true" class="textboxes passBox" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" /></div>
 <button type="submit" name="submit"  data-corners="false" data-theme="b>Login</button> 
 </form> 
 </div> 

Js page look likes:

submitHandler: function(form) {
              $.mobile.loading('show');
              $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"http://xxxx.com/services/login.php",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        data:{username : $("#email").val(), password : $("#password").val()},
                        dataType:'json',
                        success:function(response) 
                                    {    
                                           $.mobile.loading( 'hide');
                                          var response = response.item;
                                          var datas    = response.user_nicename;
                                          var dataID   = response.ID;

                                          if(typeof response =='object')
                                         {
                                            localStorage.myname = datas;
                                            localStorage.myId   = dataID;
                                            $.mobile.changePage("home.html", {transition: 'slide', reverse: 'true' });                          


                                         }
}   });
}
```

In this login.js my mobile changepage is home.html, the above localStorage.myId = dataID how to pass in home.html page like below:

home.html page

```
<div data-role="page" id="detailsPage">


</div>
```

home.js page

```
var serviceURL = "http://xxxx.com/services/";
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#detailsPage", function(){ 

       $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;  
       var id=localStorage.myID
       $.mobile.loading('show');
       $.getJSON('http://xxxx.com/services/getemployee.php?id='+id, displayEmployee);


}

Here i am very much confusing after login successfully how to pass the id from login.js page to home.js page. Please clarify my doubt. i have tried different forum answers and blogs but not getting result. i tried in this way  
$.mobile.changePage("home.html", {serviceURL:"home.html?id="+localStorage.myID, reloadPage : true, changeHash : true, transition: 'slide', reverse: 'true'});

my logcat shows the parse error at undefined in home.js page. Please guide me Thanks in Advance.
```

Answer (score 2):

localStorage is a key/value pair store. You need to use the methods provided by localStorage, examples:

```
localStorage.setItem('somekey','someStringOnly');

localStorage.getItem('somekey');
```

Use:

```
if(typeof response =='object')
{
    localStorage.setItem('myname', datas);
    localStorage.setItem('myId',dataID);
    $.mobile.changePage("home.html", {transition: 'slide', reverse: 'true' });
}
```

And

```
var id=localStorage.getItem('myId');
```

Comment: Thanks for giving reply, can you please give me small example related to my post. How i can use local storage to pass previous page id.

Comment: I tried with the above example eventhough id is not taking just success the login. Any alternative solution please reply me Sir.

Comment: Thankyou its working. i didnot change the variable in previous page.